# Visual Studio - Is there any way to search a subset of code that can be executed?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

Not sure if this is possible but given the way we can easily navigate to implementations of method calls (or at least a choice of possible implementations) and can even syntax highlight code coverage - is there any way to perform a 'search' or have an overview of all the code that CAN be run in a given highlighted section?

I.E if I highlight code

```
CallThirdParty(); // this function calls five other functions from classes X Y and Z
WriteToDatabase(); // no child function calls
PerformReconciliation(); // this function calls fourteen other functions from class A
```

Could I run a search on code that would be in classes X Y Z and A? Or at least get a view of all the code that would / could be run for that snippet?

Forgive me if it doesn't make much sense, but I think this would be absolutely awesome, especially when jumping into a project you aren't familiar with!

For Visual Studio for the question purposes but I'd be interested in any IDE / plugin that accomplishes this.

Comment: You mean [call hierarchy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd409859)? (If the method you're in is very large compared to the section, you could temporarily extract the section into its own method, or (from C# 7) a local function.)

Answer (score 0):

The [Code Map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238403.aspx) might do what you're looking for. As the article says it can help you

> - Understand the overall architecture of a .NET application.
> - Analyze dependencies surfaced in that architecture by progressively    drilling into the details.
> - Understand and analyze the impact of a proposed change to the code by    building a dependency map from a specific code element.

The [Call Hierarchy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd409859) may help too. As the article says the

> Call Hierarchy enables you to navigate through your code by displaying all calls to and from a selected method, property, or constructor. This enables you to better understand how code flows and to evaluate the effects of changes to code. You can examine several levels of code to view complex chains of method calls and additional entry points to the code, which enables you to explore all possible execution paths.

Additionally, you could always debug and step through the code to see what it does under different circumstances and then look at the call stack etc. to follow your calls and variables through.